# Надо ли брать названия магических заклинаний в кавычки?

Tags: кавычки, оформление-текста

Перечитывал Гарри Поттера и обратил внимание, что при озвучивании заклинаний не используются кавычки. Мне казалось, что они необходимы, так как заклинания являются именами собственными («Авада Кедавра», «Акцио» «Люмос» и т. д.).

Правильно ли это? Имеет ли контекст значение? Напишу три каких-нибудь примера из головы.

> — Гарри, тебе нужно использовать заклинание **«Акцио»**! — воскликнула Гермиона.

> — Сдохни! — закричал Гарри. — **Авада Кедавра**!

> Гермиона говорила ему, что нельзя использовать **«Бомбардо»** на камнях, потому
> что разлетевшиеся осколки могут оставить серьёзные раны.

Где в этих случаях нужны кавычки, а где нет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем случае кавычками выделяется не любое имя собственное — они используются в определенных темах. В этой теме кавычками выделяется **название заклинания**.

Кавыки ставятся как при наличии родового слова (*заклинание*), так и при отсутствии его, что и видно из приведенных примеров.

Но вот предложение: — *Сдохни! — закричал Гарри. — **Авада Кедавра**!*

Здесь это уже не название, а **текст самого заклинания,** совпадающий с названием.

Comment: Спасибо! Отмечу ваш ответ как решение вопроса. Однако я не совсем понял последнюю строку. А если герой подразумевает именно название заклинания? Если он просто хочет дать понять другому человеку, какое заклинание сейчас использует (допустим, активация происходит мысленно)?

Comment: Но здесь же это по смыслу понятно: это смертельное заклинание, которое герой явно хочет использовать по назначению, судя по предыдущему восклицанию. И он громко  его произносит (закричал Гарри). Именно от решения этого вопроса в каждом случае зависит использование кавычек (название  заклинания или озвучивание его  текста).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.